# Editing Nimbus look and feel core files

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, nimbus

I have Nimbus source files (extracted from source.zip). How do I change them and than create a new L&F out of them?

I don't want to change anything on runtime but prior to compiling my program and add my L&F as a resource.

Comment: `Nimbus` look and feel is made with `Synth` which uses `XML`. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/synth.html

Comment: I just have to change several values and i want to avoid doing it on runtime... Is there no simpler way of doing that?

Comment: Then try editing the `Nimbus` source and also compile it along with your application. But why do you want to edit `Nimbus` when it's so cool?

Comment: Well, I asked in another question, but there is a change that string key values (for strings in predefined componetns, such as JFileChooser, e.g. "File name:" string) are L&F specific. Since I want my user to be able to change inbetween themes(L&Fs), I thought I'd find those keys and change them so they have a universal name, making translating my application a whole lot easier, which was the whole point of asking this...

Comment: this looks like the 3. question about the same issue - and still I don't understand what you are _really_ after (tweaking LAF code just to localize/customize some string values definitely is the wrong thingy to do) - so: what do you _really_ want to achieve? Please show an SSCCE that demonstrates what you are doing, what you want to change and how that is LAF dependent.

Comment: Well, I've come to conlusion that what I want is unnecesarry... However, is there a way to make Nimus L&F work on a Java version prior to one where it was added by, e.g. importing it as a resource?